# Metacircular evaluator, implementing the environment

Tags: lisp, scheme, interpreter, sicp, metacircular

I am trying to implement the Metacircular Evaluator in Scheme according to the well-known book "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" by Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman.

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node79.html, http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node80.html

Authors suggest to setup environment in this way:

```
(define (define-variable! var val env)
  (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
    (define (scan vars vals)
      (cond ((null? vars)
             (add-binding-to-frame! var val frame))
            ((eq? var (car vars))
             (set-car! vals val))
            (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals)))))
    (scan (frame-variables frame)
          (frame-values frame))))

(define (setup-environment)
  (let ((initial-env
         (extend-environment (primitive-procedure-names)
                             (primitive-procedure-objects)
                             the-empty-environment)))
    (define-variable! 'true true initial-env)
    (define-variable! 'false false initial-env)
    initial-env))
```

However, I can’t understand why

```
(define myenv (setup-environment))
```

should work as we expect in Scheme, because, as I know, Scheme by default passing variables to function by value, therefore after two times applying “define-variable!” to initial-env, initial-env won't be changed each time, and the setup-environment function will return the value as the extend-environment has returned it.

Where is my mistake in understanding, could you advise, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question could be a *teensy* bit more specific, but I believe I understand it.

Specifically, your question appears to be this:

"I'm surprised by the behavior of

```
(define myenv (setup-environment))
(define-variable! 'a 13 myenv)
(lookup myenv 'a)
```

Specifically, I would expect it to fail, because Scheme is call-by-value." Is this your question?

If so, then I think I can answer it.  Call-by-value *doesn't* mean that values can't change.  It just means that function calls involve passing values from caller to callee. In fact, nearly all languages are call-by-value; this term is widely misunderstood.  Java, for instance, is also a call-by-value language.

There's nothing about Scheme, then, that prevents you from changing, or "mutating", a value. In this example, the `set-car!` call mutates the list that it's referring to. This change is then visible to any piece of code that can "see" this value.

I think your fundamental question really has to do with what "call-by-value" means, and I hope I've shed some light on it.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people think languages are not "pass-by-value", when really they are, they're just "pass-reference-by-value".

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I was not very accurate in my question, excuse me, please, for it. Will try to be clearer next time.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how this works, first of all you have to understand that the variable `initial-env` will point to the *first frame* of the environment, and this reference is *never* modified. The environment itself is a list of frames, and each frame is a pair of lists, the `car` of the first frame is the head of the list of variables, and the `cdr` of the first frame is the head of the list of values.

Once that is clear, you need to be aware of how the procedures `scan` and `add-binding-to-frame!` work. `Scan` will look inside the current frame, in the list of variables, for a variable with the same name as `var`; if found it will replace the corresponding value in the list of values. If the variable wasn't found, `add-binding-to-frame!` will add a new variable and a new value at the head of the corresponding lists, updating the frame to point to this new heads. Notice that `initial-environment` is still pointing to the first frame, and the first frame is still pointing to the heads of its lists of variables and values (but with a new binding).

So you see now, even though `initial-env` was never changed, the lists it contains were modified in place, therefore adding new variables with their respective values. I believe the best way to understand the whole process is to grab a pen and a paper and to draw, step-by-step, the result of modifying the cons cells involved.

Comment: @Alfucio if this answer was helpful in any way for you, an upvote would be nice :)

Comment: Yes, I'm very sorry for two things: firstly, that I am not able to mark your answer as an accepted too (tttt, it is very strange for me that I'm not able to it here, because I believe there're often many accepted answers, e.g., as for my current question), although I consider your answer as well helpful as first one (and I decided to mark first one only because it was first :) ); secondly, that I am not able to upvote your answer now, because I still have only 13 reputation points. I will surely upvote your post as soon I will receive 15 p. Again, thank you very much, it was really helpful!